# Does Ubuntu index thumbnails?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, filemanager

To keep things quick, does Ubuntu index thumbnails so that, next time I enter that folder, it doesn't have to reload the thumbnails? (This would be especially important in large picture folders.)

Comment: Y U ASK 16 QUESTIONS AND NO ACCEPT?! but seriously, you should go over your asked question list and review to see if any can be accepted yet. This is a community of Q and **A**. Rep aside, it is nice to know when a answer has actually solved the issue at hand.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: Just remember that the questions and answers may be helpful to others in the future, knowing which one actually solved your problem may stop someone else from a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. More specifically, it is the file manager that does this. Normally there is a limit to the size of files that are indexed however, and also it usually does not index remote files IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

See the hidden directory *.thumbnails* in your home directory.